# Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP

Tags: sql, azure, bcp

Trying to import data into Azure.
Created a text file in Management Studio 2005.
I have tried both a comma and tab delimited text file.

BCP  IN   -c -t, -r\n -U  -S  -P 
I get the error {SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data file

Here is the script I used to create the file:

```
 SELECT top 10  [Id]
      ,[RecordId]
      ,[PracticeId]
      ,[MonthEndId]
      ,ISNULL(CAST(InvoiceItemId AS VARCHAR(50)),'') AS InvoiceItemId
      ,[Date]
      ,[Number]
      ,[RecordTypeId]
      ,[LedgerTypeId]
      ,[TargetLedgerTypeId]
      ,ISNULL(CAST(Tax1Id as varchar(50)),'')AS Tax1Id
      ,[Tax1Exempt]
      ,[Tax1Total]
      ,[Tax1Exemption]
      ,ISNULL(CAST([Tax2Id] AS VARCHAR(50)),'') AS Tax2Id
      ,[Tax2Exempt]
      ,[Tax2Total]
      ,[Tax2Exemption]
      ,[TotalTaxable]
      ,[TotalTax]
      ,[TotalWithTax]
      ,[Unassigned]
      ,ISNULL(CAST([ReversingTypeId] AS VARCHAR(50)),'') AS ReversingTypeId
      ,[IncludeAccrualDoctor]
      ,12 AS InstanceId
  FROM <table>
```

Here is the table it is inserted into

```
CREATE TABLE [WS].[ARFinancialRecord](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RecordId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PracticeId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [MonthEndId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceItemId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [Number] [varchar](17) NOT NULL,
    [RecordTypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [LedgerTypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [TargetLedgerTypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Tax1Id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Tax1Exempt] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Tax1Total] [decimal](30, 8) NOT NULL,
    [Tax1Exemption] [decimal](30, 8) NOT NULL,
    [Tax2Id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Tax2Exempt] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Tax2Total] [decimal](30, 8) NOT NULL,
    [Tax2Exemption] [decimal](30, 8) NOT NULL,
    [TotalTaxable] [decimal](30, 8) NOT NULL,
    [TotalTax] [decimal](30, 8) NOT NULL,
    [TotalWithTax] [decimal](30, 8) NOT NULL,
    [Unassigned] [decimal](30, 8) NOT NULL,
    [ReversingTypeId] [tinyint] NULL,
    [IncludeAccrualDoctor] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [InstanceId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ARFinancialRecord] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

There are actually several hundred thousand actual records and I have done this from a different server, the only difference being the version of management studio.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295174/unexpected-eof-encountered-in-bcp-data-file/52295180#52295180

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file is tab-delimited then the command line flag for the column separator should be `-t\t` `-t,`

Comment: should it be `-t"\t"`?  Like i did `-S"ServerName" -U"UserName"`?  Also, what is `-t,`?

Comment: no don't use quotes, `-t` is short for field terminator i think

Comment: Actualy `tab` separated values is the default value for `bcp` so you don't have to specify any `-t` and `-r` at all. That's what I experienced by myself

Answer (score 6):

Just an FYI that I encountered this same exact error and it turned out that my destination table contained one extra column than the DAT file!

Answer (score 6):

I will share my experience with this issue. My users were sending me UTF-8 encoding and everything was working fine. My load started to fail when they updated the encoding to Encode in UCS-2 LE BOM. Use notepad++ to check these setting.

Reverting back to UTF-8 fixed my problem.

This [link](https://shades-of-orange.com/post/Unexpected-EOF-encountered-in-BCP-data-file) helped me resolving my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

"Unexpected EOF" normally means means the column or row terminator is not what you expect
That is, your command line arguments for these do match the file

Typical causes:

- Unix vs Windows line endings
- Text data containing your column delimiter (comma in actual data)
- Or a mix of the two.

SSMS should have nothing to do with it: it's the format (expected vs actual) that matters

Comment: Well I opened it in Notepad++ and the row terminator is CRLF. No embedded commas that I could find, but was getting the same error when I tab delimited it.

Comment: @alemus: Your command line has `-r\n` which is LF. It's possible the CR is confusing things.

Answer (score 5):

I every case that I have encountered this error, it ends up being an issue where the number of columns in the table do not the match the number of columns delimited in the text file. The easy way to confirm this is to load the text file into excel and compare the column count to that of the table.

Comment: I found that I needed to add a placeholder for my ID column value in the import file, even though it's an autogenerated index column.  Seems to need that placeholder.

Answer (score 4):

I think most of us prefer real-world examples than syntax hints, so here's what I did:

**bcp LoadDB.dbo.test in C:\temp\test.txt -S 123.66.108.207 -U testuser -P testpass -c -r /r**

My data was an extract from a Unix-based Oracle DB which was tab delimited and had an LF end of line character.

Because my data was tab delimited I did not specify a -t parameter, the bcp default is tab.

Because my row terminator was a LineFeed (LF) character, then I used -r /r

Because my data was all being loaded into char fields I used the -c parameter

Answer (score 2):

Open the CSV file in EXCEL and "save as" new CSV file

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this puzzle is insidious.
I spent time that I can never get back...

If you're in Windows, use NotePad++ and under "Encoding" on the menu, change it to:

**UCS-2 LE BOM**

LE = Little Endian...

Such a hateful error! And I just installed SQL Server 2019 and the latest SQLCMD/BCP tools. Seems this error has been around for a while.

This guy saved my life: https://shades-of-orange.com/post/Unexpected-EOF-encountered-in-BCP-data-file

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error while trying to bcp in the records from datafile to table. A workaround which works is just open the file in Notepad++ or similar editor and add extra line at the end of the file.This worked for my case - field separator - |^|, row separator - new line (LRCF).

**Command used: bcp  in  -T -c -t"|^|"**

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was that the record I was trying to import had an invalid foreign key

Answer (score 0):

For my case, Im trying to import a csv file into the Azure SQL Server, and i used the following syntax

BCP [databasename].dbo.[tablename] IN [localfolder][filename].csv -S [servername] -U [username]@[servername] -P [password] -c -t,

- be extra careful on the '**-t,**'

worked for me :')