# [ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

Tags: sql-server-2014

Has anyone encounter the problem mention above? This error was generated when I'm running bcp using powershell on windows 10. Is there any different running using CMD?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339092/unexpected-eof-encountered-in-bcp)

Comment: ^ Judging by @TuğcaEker's response, I believe the answer to your question is "Yes".