# Error in Importing Pipe delimited data with BCP in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssms, bcp

I am trying to import pipe delimited data with BCP in SQL server but getting error.
I have tried all the possible solution on the internet but couldn't get through.

Sample data -

```
1000004178|Valentin|FR12562062232|Valentin|Che St Georges| | |Alfortville|FR|2021-06-28 16:26:58|2021-06-28 16:26:58
1000007913|INDUSTRIAS MOLINERAS Y AFINES DEL NORTE S.A.C.I.A.|Z|INDUSTRIAS MOLINERAS Y AFINES DEL NORTE S.A.C.I.A.|Bv. Hipolito Yrigoyen|1648| |Reconquista|AR|2021-06-28 16:26:58.827|2021-06-28 16:26:58.827
1000011097|MARTINI RINALDO|MRTRLD46E16C139J|MARTINI RINALDO|VIA MASSIMO D' AZEGLIO 3| | |CERRO MAGGIORE|IT|2021-06-28 16:26:58.827|2021-06-28 16:26:58.827
1000017707|Energo stroj OOO||?????? ????? ???|??. ????????, ?. 18, ????. 2| | |??????|RU|2021-06-28 16:26:58.827|2021-06-28 16:26:58.827
```

Table schema -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.sample(
    [PartyID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [VATNumber] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [LegalName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [AddressLine1] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [AddressLine2] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [AddressLine3] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    );
```

> Enter the file storage type of field PartyID [bigint]: Enter
> prefix-length of field PartyID [0]: Enter field terminator [none]: |
>
> Enter the file storage type of field Name [nvarchar]: Enter
> prefix-length of field Name [2]: 0 Enter length of field Name [510]:
> Enter field terminator [none]: |
>
> Enter the file storage type of field VATNumber [char]: Enter
> prefix-length of field VATNumber [2]: 0 Enter length of field
> VATNumber [255]: Enter field terminator [none]: |
>
> Enter the file storage type of field LegalName [nvarchar]: Enter
> prefix-length of field LegalName [2]: 0 Enter length of field
> LegalName [510]: Enter field terminator [none]: |
>
> Enter the file storage type of field AddressLine1 [nvarchar]: Enter
> prefix-length of field AddressLine1 [2]: 0 Enter length of field
> AddressLine1 [1000]: Enter field terminator [none]: |
>
> Enter the file storage type of field AddressLine2 [nvarchar]: Enter
> prefix-length of field AddressLine2 [2]: 0 Enter length of field
> AddressLine2 [1000]: Enter field terminator [none]: |
>
> Enter the file storage type of field AddressLine3 [nvarchar]: Enter
> prefix-length of field AddressLine3 [2]: 0 Enter length of field
> AddressLine3 [1000]: Enter field terminator [none]: |
>
> Enter the file storage type of field City [nvarchar]: Enter
> prefix-length of field City [2]: 0 Enter length of field City [200]:
> Enter field terminator [none]: |
>
> Enter the file storage type of field Country [nvarchar]: Enter
> prefix-length of field Country [2]: 0 Enter length of field Country
> [200]: Enter field terminator [none]: |
>
> Enter the file storage type of field CreatedDate [datetime]: Enter
> prefix-length of field CreatedDate [0]: Enter field terminator [none]:
> |
>
> Enter the file storage type of field UpdatedDate [datetime]: Enter
> prefix-length of field UpdatedDate [0]: Enter field terminator [none]:
> \n
>
> Do you want to save this format information in a file? [Y/n] n
>
> Starting copy... SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error =
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered
> in BCP data-file
>
> 0 rows copied. Network packet size (bytes): 4096 Clock Time (ms.)
> Total     : 1

The above is the code which I'm trying and not working.

```
bcp dbo.[sample]  in C:\sample.txt -S <serverInstance> -U <username> -P <pwd>
```

trying the above bcp command.

Comment: theres simply too many different things that can cause this and you havent really given us enough information to assist with. Can you go through this similar page and see if any of it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339092/unexpected-eof-encountered-in-bcp

Comment: Can you please tell me how to import data with unicode characters using bcp? @DougCoats

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339092/unexpected-eof-encountered-in-bcp)

Answer (score 0):

If by "Unicode characters" you mean that the `sample.txt` file uses a UCS-2 encoding then there's some work you need to do. The error message that you're reporting is likely because the `sample.txt` file starts with a U+FEFF byte order mark (i.e.: the bytes FF FE):

```
 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file
```

First Step: The `bcp.exe` tool doesn't understand byte order marks, so you can remove them from your file. You can do that with some PowerShell like this...

```
[Byte[]] $RawBytes = Get-Content "sample.txt" -AsBytestream -Raw
# Remove the U+FEFF byte order mark...
if ($RawBytes[0] -eq 255 -and $RawBytes[1] -eq 254) {
    $RawBytes = $RawBytes[2..($RawBytes.Length - 2)]
}
# Write the BOM-free result...
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("sample-nobom.txt", $RawBytes);
```

Second step: Generate a "BCP Format" file for Unicode import...

```
bcp dbo.[sample] format nul -f sample.fmt -w "-t|" -S <serverInstance> -U <username> -P <pwd>
```

Note:

- the `-t` parameter specifies the field terminator character. We need to quote the parameter in this case because the `|` is a special command shell character.
- the `-w` parameter enables Unicode character import/export

This will generate a `sample.fmt` format file similar to the following (your collation may be different):

```
14.0
11
1       SQLNCHAR            0       42      "|\0"        1     PartyID                      ""
2       SQLNCHAR            0       510     "|\0"        2     Name                         Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
3       SQLNCHAR            0       510     "|\0"        3     VATNumber                    Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
4       SQLNCHAR            0       510     "|\0"        4     LegalName                    Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
5       SQLNCHAR            0       1000    "|\0"        5     AddressLine1                 Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
6       SQLNCHAR            0       1000    "|\0"        6     AddressLine2                 Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
7       SQLNCHAR            0       1000    "|\0"        7     AddressLine3                 Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
8       SQLNCHAR            0       200     "|\0"        8     City                         Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
9       SQLNCHAR            0       200     "|\0"        9     Country                      Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
10      SQLNCHAR            0       48      "|\0"        10    CreatedDate                  ""
11      SQLNCHAR            0       48      "\r\0\n\0"   11    UpdatedDate                  ""
```

Third step: Import your (now BOM-free) sample data...

```
bcp dbo.[sample] in sample-nobom.txt -f sample.fmt -w -S <serverInstance> -U <username> -P <pwd>
```

See the [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) reference for more information about commandline parameters/switches.